# Upload S3 from on-premise host?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, .net-core

I'm following the following link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html
to upload files from local machine to an S3 bucket on VPC. The application is also testing and running on the on-premise machine.

```
var s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(RegionEndpoint.USEast2);
var fileTransferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3Client);
await fileTransferUtility.UploadAsync("c:\tmp\test.txt", "bucketName");
```

However, the code gets the following error.

> A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network

Should an Url be given?

---

Here is the network traffic captured by Fiddler. However, it gets a different exception for the code.

```
GET http://1xx.1xx.1xx.2xx/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials HTTP/1.1
Host: 1xx.1xx.1xx.2xx


HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 787


Network Error










Network Error (tcp_error)








A communication error occurred: "Operation timed out"




The Web Server may be down, too busy, or experiencing other problems preventing it from responding to requests. You may wish to try again at a later time.






For assistance, contact your network support team.
```

### `.aws\config`

```
[default]
region = USWest2
```

Comment: Can you post your configuration WITHOUT your secret key?

Comment: My immediate next step would be a quick Wireshark trace to see what it was trying to reach out to.  Are you behind a corporate (or otherwise) firewall?

Comment: @TheSoftwareJedi, do you know where to find the configuration/profile file? I cannot find the .aws folder on the Windows machine.

Comment: On Windows the credentials file is located at C:\Users\<username>\.aws\credentials. If the directory .aws is missing in your home folder, then you have not run the command "aws configure" to setup your AWS environment.

Comment: @JohnHanley, it was not there so I run `aws configure` and set it up (only for the `region`)

Comment: In your Fiddler code you are trying to access EC2 metadata. This is only available for access inside the instance. You cannot access metadata from outside the instance. Without credentials, your code will not work. Why did you only setup regions with the Access Key?

Comment: @JohnHanley, we are not allowed to use `access key ID` and `Secret Access Key`. Is it another way?

Comment: From onprem you will need access keys. Inside EC2 you can assign a role to the instance to provide access keys in the metadata which the SDK will automatically pickup.

Comment: @JohnHanley, will the application running in a Docker container in EC2 will also pick up the role/key assigned to the EC2?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error today, even though I had a valid `$USERPROFILE\.aws\credentials` file - it was actually because `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json` couldn't be decrypted (not sure why), which causes AWS to think you don't have have local credentials, and hence tries to make a connection to the EC2 metadata URL which is http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/?. On a local development machine that won't be accessible.  For me, deleting the `$USERPROFILE\AppData\Local\AWSToolkit\RegisteredAccounts.json` file did the trick.  FWIW, I only managed to figure this out by reading through the source of the AWS SDK...

Comment: I had this same cryptic error message. Your response led me to resolve mine by removing my $USERPROFILE\.aws directory and recreating it with "aws configure"